Checkmarx Stored XSS Issue even with JSNENCODE
We are running Checkmarx report for our Visaulforce pages. In apex controller, we are getting the record name using SOQL query and then we are passing that record name in the onClick event of apex:outputLink/. We have used JSENCODE while passing the record name in the onClick.
But we are still getting the Stored XSS issue while running the Checkmarx report.
I have attahced the screenshot of the Checkmarx report item.
Can you help us resolving this issue?

